# Is a 'root' an intrinsic property of a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Is *root* an intrinsic property of a given tree?(Given a tree, can you uniquely determine the root?) Can't any vertex of a tree be chosen as a root? Aren't all trees rooted in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just one common example of a [pointed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set) (or rooted set). Given any **non-empty** set, any one of the elements can be chosen to be the root. The result is a rooted set. That is, a set with the extra structure of a root. Thus, there is one set, but many rooted sets with the same underlying set. Therefore, a root is **not** an intrinsic property of a set, but it is an intrinsic part of a rooted set.

Notice that this is much different than, for example, the center of a tree as described in [MSE question 1874429](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1874429) "The center of a tree is a vertex or an edge." which is unique for a given tree.

Answer (score 2):

NO; not necessarily a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) has a *root*.

A [rooted tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Rooted_tree) is a tree in which one vertex has been designated the root.

Comment: I don't agree with you when you say "not necessarily a tree has a root": in a tree (i.e. connected acyclic graph) any vertex can be chosen as a root. Choosing a root in a tree just means to fix an order in the tree. I agree with you if you mean that there are trees that are not rooted in the sense that the root for that tree has not been chosen explicitly (i.e. the order has not been fixed), but it is always possible to chose a root.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco - if we can choose a vertex whatever and call it *root*, it seems hard to me call it "an intrinsic properrty" of the tree.

Comment: Now I see better what you mean, thank you. Maybe we can say that the existence of a root in a (non-empty) tree is an intrinsic property of the tree, but the tree does not determine univocally its root (if it has more that one vertex).

Comment: What @Taroccoesbrocco 's telling is exactly what I had in mind. By "intrinsic" I meant, given the tree, can you uniquely determine the root? If you can, please tell the algorithm. To conclude, just because no vertex has been thought of as the root, is it an unrooted tree?